# Accidentally mounted shared folder to /media/, how to fix?

Tags: fedora, windows, virtualbox, file-sharing, shared-folders

While trying to fix a problem with shared folders, I accidentally set up my shared folder (the C drive) to mount at `/media/`, not something like `/media/sf_C_DRIVE`. Now my entire /media folder is just some kind of link to my C drive. (IE, `/media/` contains the recycle bin, Desktop, Program Files (x86), etc)

How do I fix this? When I try to `sudo rmdir /media` hoping it would just destroy the link (and not my C drive) it says that "device or resource busy".

I removed the shared folder in Virtualbox but that appears to have done nothing.

**I can no longer insert any kind of external drive**. Normally they would appear in /media, but now they cannot..since /media is my C drive. That's bad.

Trying `sudo umount /media/` results in "target is busy".

Answer (score 0):

Despite removing it from Virtualbox, it appears a different shared folder was still there.

After removing it from Virtualbox's settings, /media/ was no longer mounted.

Comment: Is in now fixed?